# Processing Script Editor shows spaces as tabs

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm using the processing script editor in QGIS 3.2 (Bonn). The display is messed up. Spaces are shown as tabs and there is a random tab in between a name and the () to run a command. As a consequence, nothing runs correctly.

Below is an short, nonsense example.  Does anyone know more about this?

[image]

Comment: Please note that gis.stackexchange is a platform to ask and answer questions. If you want to report a bug or provide a bug fix, please use the appropriate bug tracker or code repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue and have opened a ticket at https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20349